# What is the meaning of double percentage signs with square brackets?

Tags: marketing-cloud, code, landing-page

I am currently working inside a Marketing Cloud Landing Page.
The page has code inside an HTML block. Some of the code is within a script tag like this

> <script type="text/javascript">CODE</script>

Which I can understand, as being javascript code.

But other code is enclosed with double percentage signs and square brackets like this.

> %%[CODE]%%

Which I don't quite understand and sadly couldn't find anything about online.

What does it mean if code is within these characters? What programming language is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%[<code here>]%%` means that the code contained is [AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ampscript.html). A proprietary, embeddable language (php would be another example of an embeddable language) used on Salesforce's Marketing Cloud.

There are [a collection of modules/trails dedicated to AMPscript](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search/learning?keywords=AMPscript) on trailhead that should help you get started.